# Standard Matrix Co-ordinates Must Be Less Than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

(I can't post images until I have at least 10 reputation, so bear with me here).

There's a question in my textbook that goes:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23889576/Screenshots/StackExchange/1350.png

The answer that's shown states:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23889576/Screenshots/StackExchange/1351.png

Why does the -25/13 convert to -12/13 in the final answer? Is it true that a standard matrix cannot have co-ordinates greater than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo in the book. Notice that

$$1-5\frac{10}{26}=-\frac{12}{13}$$

The $-25/13$ is simply a mistake.

You can check this. Suppose the matrix actually should include $-25/13$, then it should fix the line $x_1-5x_2=0$. Well, consider a vector $[5,1]^{\top}$:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} 12/13 & 5/13 \\ 5/13 & -25/13\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 1\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$$

Clearly $x_1=5$ and $x_2=0$ *does not* satisfy $x_1-5x_2=0$. The matrix does not fix the line.